# Primefaces StreamedContents download by one button

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

In the code, 3 buttons download each file using <p:fileDownload but My purpose is , click one button and download 3 files or zip.I dont know how to use. I guess StreamedContent does not provide List

```
                        <p:commandButton id="download" value="SAV " ajax="false" rendered="true" icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s"
                            update=":growlMessage,:form:verinotlari,:form,:diyalog"
                            actionListener="#{XXBean.onDownloadClickRaw}"
                            oncomplete="document.getElementById('form:refresh').click();">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{XXBean.downloadFileSAV}" />
                        </p:commandButton>                          
                        <p:commandButton id="download" value="DYR" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s"
                            update=":growlMessage,:form:verinotlari,:form,:diyalog">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{XXBean.downloadFileDYR}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton id="download" value="IEC" ajax="false" rendered="true" icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s"
                            update=":growlMessage,:form:verinotlari,:form,:diyalog">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{XXBean.downloadFileIEC}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
```

Bean

```
private StreamedContent downloadFileSAV;
private StreamedContent downloadFileDYR;
private StreamedContent downloadFileIEC;

private InputStream fileSAV;
private InputStream fileDYR;
private InputStream fileIEC;

public void onDownloadClickRaw() {

    if (psseAnaliz.isKontrolcuModelleme()) {
        downloadFileDYR = PrimeFacesFolderService.streamedContentDonustur(psseAnaliz.getFolderName() + ".dyr", "application/.dyr", fileDYR);
    }

    downloadFileSAV = PrimeFacesFolderService.streamedContentDonustur(psseAnaliz.getFolderName() + ".sav", "application/.sav", fileSAV);

    downloadFileIEC = PrimeFacesFolderService.streamedContentDonustur(psseAnaliz.getFolderName() + ".iec", "application/.iec", fileIEC);

}
```

Comment: You need to create your own zip for now. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6273

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there any way to do that without zipping files ?

Comment: You might be able to do so with the PF10 Ajax download and a bit of customizing to trigger 3 downloads. https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/filedownload?id=ajax-downloading